# arshaw fullcalendar : disable the click event in month view and all day in agendaweek and agenda day

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to disable the click event on all day places and want the user to be able to click just in time slots but not the allday slot.

For that:
In month view : it should not be click-able, same in agendaWeek and agendaDay the top slot of allDay should not be clickable but the rest of the calendar must be fine and clickable as it is working for me.

In short allDay slot needs to be unclickable.

Comment: Which view are you talking about and what happens now when you click?

Comment: I am taking time when user clicks on agendaWeek,agendaDay or month view in time slots but when user click in proper timings slots in Week and Day view then it is fine BUT when user click on month view or allDay(top) slot in WEEK and DAY view the timings come to me are 00:00 which is not what I want.

Comment: Could you provide your code,please?

Comment: Please remember, you have an option to make the all-day slot invisible. "allDaySlot:false". If it meets your requirements you can hide allDay slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) is the page in the documentation you need.  See my example below.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        if(allDay){
            alert('That is not a valid time slot!');
            return;
        } else {
            // run your code here if a slot with valid time was selected.
        }
    }
});
```